# Save Dynamic Array To MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, session

I have a dynamic `form` that allows users to enter information and that `form` can be submitted multiple times and the page will show all of the inputted data thanks to `$_SESSION`. That information is sent to another page where it will be saved to a MySQL database after submission.

I can't get it to save all of the information. If I have 3 groups of data, it will only write the last one into the database. **How do I save the entire array to the database?**

*This is the page that shows all of the dynamic information:*

```
    <?php
        $invoice_no = $_SESSION['invoice'];
        if(isset($_SESSION['order'])) : 

            foreach($_SESSION['order'] as $sav) {
            ?>
            <form action="addrow.php" method="post">
            <label>Length</label><input type="text" name="length" value="<?php echo $sav['length']; ?>" size="2">
            <label>Width</label><input type="text" name="width" value="<?php echo $sav['width']; ?>" size="2">
            <label>Color</label><input type="text" name="color" value="<?php echo $sav['color']; ?>" size="4">
            <label>Quantity</label><input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $sav['quantity']; ?>" size="2">
            <label>Invoice Is Hidden</label><input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="<?php echo $invoice_no; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="total" value="<?php echo $sav['total']; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="PaymentStatus" value="PAID">
            <br>
            <?php } endif; ?>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="upload">
            </form>
```

*This page saves it to the database. I was unsure of how to save the array into the database, so I used the same code to show the session data and I modified it but failed:*

```
    <?php
require("addrow_info.php");

if(isset($_POST['upload'])) :

$decal = array(
    'length' => $_POST['length'],
    'width' => $_POST['width'],
    'color' => $_POST['color'],
    'quantity' => $_POST['quantity'],
    'total' => $_POST['total'],
    'invoice' => $_POST['invoice'],
    'paymentStatus' => $_POST['PaymentStatus'],
    'submit' => $_POST['upload']
 );

 $_POST['order'][] = $decal;

endif;


if(isset($_POST['order'])) : 
foreach($_POST['order'] as $newOrder) {


// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ("localhost", $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

 // Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Insert new row with user data
$query = "INSERT INTO orders (PaymentStatus, invoice_no, length, width, color,   quantity, total ) VALUES  ('".$newOrder['paymentStatus']."','".$newOrder['invoice']."','".$newOrder['length']."', '".$newOrder['width']."', '".$newOrder['color']."', '".$newOrder['quantity']."', '".$newOrder['total']."')";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());

echo "$query";

mysql_close();
}

} endif;

header ("location:/thankyou.php");

?>
```

I was reading about using the `serialize()` function but I'm not sure if that's best for what I'm trying to accomplish. I want each group of data to save in one row under their respective column.

It should look like this:

```
Length    Width    Color    Invoice    Quantity    Total    PaymentStatus
5         5        Green    abc123     1           2.00     PAID <--Each row is a group
6         6        blue     def234     2           3.00     PAID
```

**What is the best solution for saving an `array` into a MySQL database?**

Comment: The best solution for saving an array in a database is to normalize your data so you can run proper queries.

Comment: By the way, `mysql_query` is deprecated.  Have a look at mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <form action="addrow.php" method="post"><?php
    $invoice_no = $_SESSION['invoice'];
    if(isset($_SESSION['order'])) : 

        foreach($_SESSION['order'] as $sav) {
        ?>

        <label>Length</label><input type="text" name="length[]" value="<?php echo $sav['length']; ?>" size="2">
        <label>Width</label><input type="text" name="width[]" value="<?php echo $sav['width']; ?>" size="2">
        <label>Color</label><input type="text" name="color[]" value="<?php echo $sav['color']; ?>" size="4">
        <label>Quantity</label><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="<?php echo $sav['quantity']; ?>" size="2">
        <label>Invoice Is Hidden</label><input type="hidden" name="invoice[]" value="<?php echo $invoice_no; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="total[]" value="<?php echo $sav['total']; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="PaymentStatus" value="PAID">

        <br>
        <?php } endif; ?>
        <br><br><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="upload">
        </form>

       try it and print_r( $_POST ), I think you can make it.

if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

Array ( [length] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 ) [width] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 3 )

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['length']);$i++){
   $order = array(
       'length'=>$_POST['length'][$i], 
       'width'=>$_POST['width'][$i]),
        //...............
   );
   $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (PaymentStatus, invoice_no, length, width, color,   quantity, total ) VALUES  ('{$order['paymentStatus']}','{$order['invoice']}','{$order['length']}', '{$order['width']}', '{$order['color']}', '{$order['quantity']}', '{$order['total']}')";
   mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: what am I supposed to do with this?

Comment: I don't need help with this page. This page works fine and posts all of the session data. I need help in posting the contents from this page to the MySQL database.

Comment: it is can not success with your page(html),just use this page to post. and i wanna you see what is the different between these two page,so  i told you to use print_r($_POST); and i think you can do the last. I don't want to do the all job. i just give you a direction.

Comment: I used `print_r` on the page with 3 sets of values on the session and it returns only one set of values, the last set of the array to be specific.

Comment: This is what it gave me: `Array ( [length] => 4 [width] => 3 [color] => white [quantity] => 2 [invoice] => 2654700459Svb2UpGXN0PvcH6 [total] => 4.80 [PaymentStatus] => PAID [upload] => Submit )` It should have 3 `[length]` values and `[width]` etc.

Comment: I was able to allow it to show all of the values for each variable. It did it with arrays, so it shows `Array ( [length] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 ) [width] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 3 ) ...` But now when I try to add it to the database, the database only shows Array.

Comment: give you all ,see my answer up, for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['length']);$i++){
   $order = array(
       'length'=>$_POST['length'][$i], 
       'width'=>$_POST['width'][$i]),
        //...............
   );
   $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (PaymentStatus, invoice_no, length, width, color,   quantity, total ) VALUES  ('{$order['paymentStatus']}','{$order['invoice']}','{$order['length']}', '{$order['width']}', '{$order['color']}', '{$order['quantity']}', '{$order['total']}')";
   mysql_query($sql);
}

Comment: Awesome! That did the job. :)